# How can I preview PowerPoint files in Azure DevOps (VSTS)?

Tags: azure-devops

Given an attachment in Azure DevOps work item,
and it is of type PowerPoint,
When I click on it,
it says there is no viewer
and I must download a copy to view it.

Is there a viewer available for VSTS work item attachments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no viewers for work item attachments. But you may try to store your files on some services (sharepoint, onedrive .....) and then link work item to them by hyperlink:
[image]